# Referencing multiple lists in api loop with R

Tags: r, for-loop, google-analytics-api

I am working with a google analytics api, and need to pull out data on multiple views (n = 11, basically different databases with the same data types and formats).  However, in addition to this I need to specify the beginning and end date separately, to get each months data for multiple months (n = 6). Longer date ranges are not suitable, as the data aggregates between the specified dates.

I am using the `RGA` package for this as I need to pull out multichannel data.

My attempt pulls in the data but only for one month. I am not sure how to specify the lists of the start and end dates for each month. Happy to use a different approach if this is not optimal.
**Note**: the final `df` also needs the date bringing in relative to the view ID, which my code doesn't do.

Also please let me know if I have written this question incorrectly, and how I can improve it.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

```r
# install.packages("RGA")
library(RGA)
library(lubridate)

# get list of month dates for last 6 months
end_months <- ymd("2018-11-01") + months(0:6) - days(1)
start_months <- ymd("2018-10-01") + months(0:6)

# list of view ids required to make api call (pseudonymised)
viewId <- c(26494958, 477448251, 47843527, 96382507, 537821552, 67482819)

for (i in viewId) {
  ga_data_temp <- get_mcf(
    i, # This is a (dynamic) ViewID parameter
    start.date = "2019-01-01", end.date = "2019-01-31",
    dimensions = c('mcf:conversionGoalNumber', 'mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath'),
    metrics = c('mcf:totalConversions', 'mcf:totalConversionValue')
  )
  
  ga_data_temp$viewId <- i
  ga_data_final <- rbind(ga_data_final, ga_data_temp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `expand.grid` to build a data frame for all combinations of month and view vectors. Then iterate through columns elementwise with `Map` which builds a list of data frames to be row binded once at the end (highly advised alternative than using `rbind` inside of a loop). Also use `within` to add the *viewId* column:

```
params_df <- expand.grid(start_months=start_months, end_months=end_months, viewId=viewId)

get_api_data <- function(str, end, vId)
    within(get_mcf(vId,                          # =This is a (dynamic) ViewID parameter
                   start.date = str, end.date = end,
                   dimensions=c('mcf:conversionGoalNumber', 'mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath'),
                   metrics=c('mcf:totalConversions', 'mcf:totalConversionValue')),
           viewId <- vId)
)

# ELEMENT-WISE LOOP
df_list <- Map(get_api_data, params_df$start_month, params_df$end_month, params_df$viewId)
# df_list <- with(params_df, Map(get_api_data, start_month, end_month, viewId))  

# BIND ALL DF ELEMENTS TOGETHER
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, sorry for the late reply, I only got to try this  today. The api function code is great, however there are a few issues, one of which I neglected in the original question. With expand.grid we have every permutation of dates and view id, but this should be just the start and end date of each month. The second issue, is how do we bring through these dates in the call so that we have them in the final_df dataframe next to the appropriate ID? Thanks for you help so far

Comment: Not understanding as *start_months* and *end_months* vectors should be start and end of each month. Are you saying days between 2-29 are showing up? As for second, you can add new date columns inside `within` just as we did for *viewId* assigning to param *vId*.